# How to send file in a "PUT" method when HTML has no "PUT"?

Tags: spring-mvc

I have a Controller like this:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/user/", method = RequestMethod.PUT, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public @ResponseBody UserLesserDTO createUser(@RequestParam("profileImage") MultipartFile file, @RequestBody UserDTO user) {
    System.out.println("Creating User " + user.getName() );

    try {
        UserDTO userTest = userService.getUserByUsername( user.getName() );
        return new UserLesserDTO( userTest );
    } catch ( NoResultException e ) {
        //
    }
    return new UserLesserDTO( userService.addUser(user) );
}
```

and a form to create the user.

This form have a `input type file` named `profileImage`.

My question is: As I can't send a `PUT` method in HTML, I MUST send it as an Ajax request converting all form attributes to a JSON object and send it as `PUT`. But I need to send a file too and I don't know how to proceed.

Comment: There is nothing called PUT in HTML and can't be. HTML is just a markup language and for communicating with the server you either use HTML form (that is treated specially) of JavaScript. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2320069/jquery-ajax-file-upload) you can find some useful stuff of how to upload via AJAX.

Comment: Ok. I know I must to respect the purpose of the PUT and POST methods but I need (love) to keep things simple too. I just create  `/user/create/` and `/user/update/` mappings both accepting `POST`. Please do not blame me for it.

Comment: @john I'm not talking about PUT tag. I'm talking about PUT form method.